# DialogProvider error while generating a dialog angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a mobile app where a dialog is opened after clicking on an image.

Here it is what I have done so far:

**HTML:**

```
        <ion-content ng-controller="cityController">
<div class="container" id="popupContainer">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-33">
                    <img  src="img/images/opera.jpg" ng-click="showTabDialog($event)"/>
              <div class="description" style="font-size: 8pt">Opera de Lyon</div>
         </div>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('starter.cityController', ['ionic', 'ngDialog'])
.controller('cityController', function ($scope, $mdDialog, $mdMedia){
   $scope.status = '  ';
  $scope.customFullscreen = $mdMedia('xs') || $mdMedia('sm');

  $scope.showTabDialog = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: 'tabDialog.tmpl.html',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose:true
    })
        .then(function(answer) {
          $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
        }, function() {
          $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
        });
  };
});
function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.hide = function() {
    $mdDialog.hide();
  };
  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $mdDialog.cancel();
  };
  $scope.answer = function(answer) {
    $mdDialog.hide(answer);
  };
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $mdDialogProvider <- $mdDialog <- cityController
```

The template is there. I know this problem is a problem of some dependency but I cannot find out which one.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller definition should be like

```
.controller('cityController', ['$scope','$mdDialog','$mdMedia',function ($scope, $mdDialog, $mdMedia){

    // your code will be here

  }])
```

And please inject `ngMaterial` dependency to your angular module like

```
angular.module('starter.cityController', ['ngMaterial'])
```

If you cant incluse ngMaterial using bower install add manually in index.html as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've edited the answer. you need to inject the angular material dependency to your app

Comment: oh Ok. I tried installing ngMaterial but I always get bower extra-resolution unnecessary resolution .... and ngMaterial is not installed. How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi Hana, edited the code. make sure the script src of the ngmaterial should come below the angular.min.js in your index.html